# Can I view my old .zsh_history outputs

Tags: output, stdout, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I feel like someone would have asked this question before, however, I cannot find anything and it may be because it's too obvious and I'm looking in the wrong file or I'm not searching a good key term to find out.

I want to view some of my old output in the terminal (OSX) and I assumed that was stored in my .zsh_history and all I'm seeing is all my input without the outputs.

**Is there a way I can go back and view this?**

**Is there a way I can save it for future use if not?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not zsh specific, It applies to most of the shells

If you executed the commands with output redirection, 
like

```
someCommand > someFile.txt
```

or appended command output like this,

```
someCommand >> someFile.txt
```

They will be stored to the specific file. Else you would have to run each command again

[This may solve your issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Comment: It is better to provide the text of the solution here and reference the link. Link only answers are not considered good Stackoverflow practice.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Cliff Thanks for pointing out. Added some essential parts of the answer from the link.